# Descriptor data for Neural Network Classifier: how to handle site effects?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, data-preprocessing

I have input data which I want to feed into a neural network for classification. The data contains observations which were measured at 5 different sites (on 5 different scanners), and I know that the scanner has an influence on the data (there are random site effects).

How should I handle this?

My ideas so far would be to add the site ID as a categorial (1-hot encoded, so then numerical) variable to the descriptors.

Is there anything else I can do?